# Node.js - Decoded WinPcap websocket frame is cut off

Tags: node.js, websocket, pcap, winpcap

I'm trying to listen to websocket traffic using the [cap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cap) module with Node.js (4.5.0) on Windows 7. I am able to parse/decode the payload that is being captured but part of it is cut off when the payload is over a certain length.

I'm using [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514657/how-do-you-process-a-basic-websocket-frame) to decode the websocket frame (wsDecoded function) and I think the problem is that the response I'm getting from the cap module is returning the entire response in a single buffer, but this example (and some of the other websocket library's I've looked at) seem to expect to process multiple frames when the payload is over a certain size.

I've tried taking the buffer from and breaking it apart into smaller pieces but when I do that the payload just looks like random garbage.

```
var Cap = require('cap').Cap;
var decoders = require('cap').decoders;
var PROTOCOL = decoders.PROTOCOL;

var c = new Cap();
var device = Cap.findDevice(LOCAL_IP);
var filter = 'port 8088';
var bufSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
var buffer = new Buffer(65535);

var linkType = c.open(device, filter, bufSize, buffer);

c.setMinBytes && c.setMinBytes(0);

c.on('packet', function(nbytes, trunc) {
  if (linkType === 'ETHERNET') {
    var ret = decoders.Ethernet(buffer);

    if (ret.info.type === PROTOCOL.ETHERNET.IPV4) {
      ret = decoders.IPV4(buffer, ret.offset);

      if (ret.info.protocol === PROTOCOL.IP.TCP) {
        var datalen = ret.info.totallen - ret.hdrlen;
        ret = decoders.TCP(buffer, ret.offset);
        datalen -= ret.hdrlen;

        var payload = wsDecoded(buffer, ret.offset, ret.offset + datalen);
        console.log(payload.toString());
      }
    }
  }
});

function wsDecoded (data, start, end) {
  var message = data.slice(start, end);
  var FIN = (message[0] & 0x80);
  var RSV1 = (message[0] & 0x40);
  var RSV2 = (message[0] & 0x20);
  var RSV3 = (message[0] & 0x10);
  var Opcode = message[0] & 0x0F;
  var mask = (message[1] & 0x80);
  var length = (message[1] & 0x7F);

  var nextByte = 2;
  if (length === 126) {
    // length = next 2 bytes
    nextByte += 2;
  } else if (length === 127){
    // length = next 8 bytes
    nextByte += 8;
  }

  var maskingKey = null;
  if (mask){
    maskingKey = message.slice(nextByte, nextByte + 4);
    nextByte += 4;
  }

  var payload = message.slice(nextByte, nextByte + length);

  if (maskingKey){
    for (var i = 0; i < payload.length; i++){
     payload[i] = payload[i] ^ maskingKey[i % 4];
    }
  }

  return payload;
}
```

Example result that is not cut off:

```
{"Command":"FoldCards","Table":"Ring Game #02","Type":"R","Ghost":"No"}
```

Example result that is cut off:

```
{"Command":"Buttons","Table":"Ring Game   #02","Type":"R","Button1":"","Button2":"Ready","Button3":"","Preflop":"No","Call":0,"M
```

Payload from on('packet') callback when using buffer.toString('binary', ret.offset, datalen). This is very close to what I need but it does not unmask the payload and leaves some random characters in (which I think are the start and stop of the frame but not 100% sure about that)

```
?'{"Command":"TablesSitting","Tables":[]}?'{"Command":"TablesWaiting","Tables":[]}?~☺({"Command":"RingGameLobby","Clear":"Yes","Count":2,"ID":["Ring Game #01","Ring Game #02"],"Game":["NL Hold'em","NL Hold'em"],"GameIndex":[2,2],"Seats":[10,10],"StakesLo":[10,10],"StakesHi":[20,20],"BuyinMin":[400,400],"BuyinMax":[2000,2000],"Players":[0,0],"Waiting":[0,0],"Password":["No","No"]}?~☺{"Command":"TournamentLobby","Clear":"Yes","Count":0,"ID":[],"SnG":[],"Shootout":[],"Game":[],"GameIndex":[],"Buyin":[],"EntryFee":[],"Rebuy":[],"TS":[],"PreReg":[],"Reg":[],"Max":[],"Starts":[],"StartMin":[],"StartTime":[],"Running":[],"Tables":[],"Password":[]}?~ ?{"Command":"Logins","Clear":"Yes","Total":1,"Player":["harrythree"],"Name":[""],"Location":["Greenville"],"Login":["2016-08-27 13:26:45"]}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the value of "certain size"? Maybe fragmentation was used: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#page-33

Comment: Also can you please compare the length of the payload data with size of the whole data buffer? Maybe websocket frame was sent not as a single tcp packet, but multiple. If this is true, you have to wait for enother tcp packet, join buffers and then read websocket frame

Comment: Editing above to show full response payload

Comment: Also, anything that is passed through the wsDecoded function is is returned with a maximum of 128 characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting truncated message becasue you didn't read payloadLength correctly.
Take a look:

```
var length = (message[1] & 0x7F);

var nextByte = 2;
if (length === 126) {
    // in this case next 2 bytes store lengths. you have to read ones from the buffer
    nextByte += 2;
} else if (length === 127){
    // in this case next 8 bytes store lengths. you have to read ones from the buffer
    nextByte += 8;
}
```

When message size is more than 125 bytes, you have to read correct payloadLength by using next 2 or 8 bytes like RFC says. In your case, you just skip these bytes, so that your "length" is always <= 127 and as result the following line produces truncated payload data:

```
var payload = message.slice(nextByte, nextByte + length);
                                                   ^
                                              always <= 127
```

I slightly modified your code to debug the problem. This is an example of the implementation I am talking about:

```
var Cap = require('cap').Cap;
var decoders = require('cap').decoders;
var PROTOCOL = decoders.PROTOCOL;

var c = new Cap();
var device = Cap.findDevice('127.0.0.1');
var filter = 'port 3001';
var bufSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
var buffer = new Buffer(bufSize);

var linkType = c.open(device, filter, bufSize, buffer);

c.setMinBytes && c.setMinBytes(0);

c.on('packet', function(nbytes, trunc) {

    console.log('************ packet: length ' + nbytes + ' bytes, truncated? '
        + (trunc ? 'yes' : 'no'));

    if (linkType === 'ETHERNET') {
        var ret = decoders.Ethernet(buffer);

        if (ret.info.type === PROTOCOL.ETHERNET.IPV4) {
            ret = decoders.IPV4(buffer, ret.offset);

            if (ret.info.protocol === PROTOCOL.IP.TCP) {
                var datalen = ret.info.totallen - ret.hdrlen;
                ret = decoders.TCP(buffer, ret.offset);
                datalen -= ret.hdrlen;

                console.log('from: ' + ret.info.srcport + ' to ' + ret.info.dstport);

                console.log("Data len: " + datalen);

                var payload = wsDecoded(buffer, ret.offset, ret.offset + datalen);
                if (payload) {
                    console.log("MSG:" + payload.toString());
                } else {
                    console.log("Invalid message");
                }

            }
        }
    }
});

function wsDecoded (data, start, end) {
    var message = data.slice(start, end);
    var index = 0;
    var FIN = (message[index] & 0x80);
    var RSV1 = (message[index] & 0x40);
    var RSV2 = (message[index] & 0x20);
    var RSV3 = (message[index] & 0x10);
    var Opcode = message[index] & 0x0F;

    index++;

    var masked = (message[index] & 0x80);
    var payloadLength = message[index] & (~0x80);
    index++;


    if (payloadLength === 126){
        // length = next 2 bytes
        payloadLength = message.readUInt16BE(index);
        index+=2;
    } else if (payloadLength === 127) {
        // read uint64
        throw new Error("Implement me");
    }

    console.log("Opcode: " + Opcode + ", fin: " + FIN + ", masked: " + masked);

    var maskingKey = null;
    if (masked){
        maskingKey = message.slice(index, index + 4);
        index += 4;
    }

    console.log("Payload length: " + payloadLength);
    var payload = message.slice(index, index + payloadLength);

    if (payload.length != payloadLength) {
        console.warn("Length mismatch");
        return false;
    }

    if (maskingKey){
        for (var i = 0; i < payload.length; i++){
            payload[i] = payload[i] ^ maskingKey[i % 4];
        }
    }

    return payload;
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and the explanation was spot on! Thanks for answering!